# Slurm pending jobs

Tags: slurm

i have a problem with slurm every job i execute keeps pending

and i dont know what to do (im new to the field)

```
scontrol: show job
JobId=484 JobName=Theileiria_project
   UserId=dhamer(1037) GroupId=Bio-info(1001) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=4294901741 Nice=0 Account=(null) QOS=normal
   JobState=PENDING Reason=BeginTime Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=481 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:00:00 TimeLimit=01:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2022-04-19T08:47:58 EligibleTime=2022-04-19T08:49:59
   AccrueTime=2022-04-19T08:49:59
   StartTime=2022-04-19T08:49:59 EndTime=2022-04-19T09:49:59 Deadline=N/A
   SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0 LastSchedEval=2022-04-19T08:47:58
   Partition=defq AllocNode:Sid=omix:377206
   ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=(null)
   BatchHost=omics001
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=30 NumTasks=30 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=30,mem=32G,node=1,billing=30
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=32G MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   OverSubscribe=NO Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Command=/home/dhamer/test.sh
   WorkDir=/home/dhamer
   StdErr=/home/dhamer/Theileiria_project.log
   StdIn=/dev/null
   StdOut=/home/dhamer/Theileiria_project.log
   Power=
```

Comment: please provide your submission command

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=serial_job_test    
#SBATCH --mail-type=END,FAIL          
#SBATCH --mail-user=test@gmail.com     # Where to send mail
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                    # Run on a single CPU
#SBATCH --mem=1gb                     # Job memory request
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00               # Time limit hrs:min:sec
#SBATCH --output=serial_test_%j.log   # Standard output and error log
pwd; hostname; date
module load python
echo "Running plot script on a single CPU core"

python /data/training/SLURM/plot_template.py
date

Answer (score 2):

`Reason=BeginTime` in the `scontrol` output means (according to `man squeue`) that "The job's earliest start time has not yet been reached." This is usually because the queue is full, or your job has low priority in the queue.

I would check with your systems administrators or your HPC helpdesk.

By the way, the submission command in your comment doesn't match the `scontrol` output, since in the script you set the timelimit to 5 minutes, but the output indicates a timelimit of 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

To check the running and pending jobs in the SLURM queue, you can run something like the following in the bash command:

```
squeue --format="%.18i %.9P %.30j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.9l %.6D %R" --states="PENDING,RUNNING"
```

If you know the partition is named "bigmem" for example you can narrow down the list of jobs returned by entering the following into the command line:

```
squeue --format="%.18i %.9P %.30j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.9l %.6D %R" --partition="bigmem" --states="PENDING,RUNNING"
```

Which will return something like:

```
             JOBID PARTITION        NAME     USER    STATE       TIME TIME_LIMI  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
           2714947    bigmem    step2.sh    user1  PENDING       0:00  12:00:00      1 (Resources)
           2206052    bigmem    mcca_jhs    user2  RUNNING 8-22:52:18 11-00:00:00    1 t0601
```